# Caption aligned right when plot.margin present ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to push the caption to the right but including the added margin (30mm right). I couldn't find any information on how to do this. Using `plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 1)` inside `theme()` doesn't work. If possible I would like pure ggplot2 solution. It needs to work in any plot (different x limits not only in this one).

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tibble(x = letters[1:4], n = 10*1:4, lab = " long thus margin") %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(x, n), n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = lab), hjust = -0.1) +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  labs(caption = "This is caption") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 30, 0, 0), "mm"))
```

[image]

Edit:

The goal is to achieve this plot:

[image]

Comment: You can have fractional values: `plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 30/40)`. Seems better, `hjust = 0` aligns left, other values should put the caption between the axis limits.

Comment: But I want to push caption to the very right edge of plot + margin of 30mm

Comment: Maybe `hjust = 1 + 30/40`? Or something like that. The problem is to have it *work in any plot*, ggplot measures are not in mm. And when I resize the plot making it wider the caption position changes.

Comment: Anything more than 1 as a value for hjust makes caption disappear.

Comment: No, I had posted that comment because I had tried it before. I just confirmed it with the value in the comment and yes, it made the caption disappear but not `hjust = 1 + 10/40`. (I chose 10 == 40 - 30).

Comment: I tested it and it seems like to make the caption reach the edge I need `hjust = 1 + 22/40`. Still, it would be great if there was a way to do this automatically like `hjust = "rmargin"` while `hjust = 1` (default) would still position it at the edge of plot area.

Comment: Like I said, I don't believe this can be done automatically, plot resizing seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the grob position of the caption just before the plot is drawn. (This is technically a pure ggplot2 solution, since the grob-hacking is done within the normal process of drawing a ggplot object.)

## Hack

Run the following line in your console:

```
trace(ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built, edit = TRUE)
```

A pop-up window should appear, showing the actual code for the traced function:

```
function (data) 
{
  plot <- data$plot
    ...
    plot_table$grobs <- plot_table$grobs[c(nrow(plot_table$layout), 
      1:(nrow(plot_table$layout) - 1))]
  }
  plot_table
}
```

Insert `plot_table$layout[which(plot_table$layout$name == "caption"), "r"] <- dim(plot_table)[2]` as a new line just before `plot_table`, towards the end:

```
function (data) 
{
  plot <- data$plot
    ...
    plot_table$grobs <- plot_table$grobs[c(nrow(plot_table$layout), 
      1:(nrow(plot_table$layout) - 1))]
  }
  plot_table$layout[which(plot_table$layout$name == "caption"), "r"] <- dim(plot_table)[2] # new
  plot_table
}
```

For the remainder of this R session, any caption in any ggplot you draw will be aligned all the way to the right of the plot's background area, rather than the plot panel. (This effect will not persist in a new session; if you want it, repeat the above steps.)

## Reversing the hack

If you wish to stop the effect within your current R session, run the following line in your console:

```
untrace(ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built)
```

Any caption in any ggplot will now be right-aligned to the plot panel again.

Answer (score 0):

`plot.caption.position =  "plot"`

Adding this to the theme worked for me.

Comment: this does not work if a plot margin is present as per question, unfortunately

Comment: This looks more like a comment than a complete answer which could include the output to demonstrate the answer resolves the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Using plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 1) inside theme() doesn't work

True, but...!

For unknown reasons, hjust actually understands values beyond c(0,1). It is fragile, because you need to manually adjust it, but it works.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = letters[1:4], n = 10*1:4, lab = " long thus margin") %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(x, n), n)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = lab), hjust = -0.1) +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  labs(caption = "This is caption") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, 30, 0, 0), "mm"),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 1.25)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>